# Determining the big-O of this loop question

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

I'm not sure about the big-O cost of this loop. Can anyone help me?
I will comment about what I think.

```
sum = 0;  // O(1)
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  for(j=0;j<i*i;j++)
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)  // run as 0+1²+2²+...+n²= n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
      sum++;  //  O(1)
```

My guess is O(N^3). Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `0+1²+2²+...+n²` steps estimation is wrong.

The innermost loop runs exactly `0+1⁴+2⁴+...+(N-1)⁴` times. This is the sum  of the first `n-1` numbers to the power of four, that is equal to `n(n-1)(6(n-1)³+9(n-1)²+n-2)/30`.

Thus the total cost is O(N<sup>5</sup>).

---

Follows another way of reaching the same result.

- The outer loop runs exactly N times.
- The middle loop runs up to `i*i` times (i.e. at most N<sup>2</sup> times) for each outer iteration.
- The inner loop runs up to `j` times (i.e. at most N<sup>2</sup> times) for each middle iteration.

Multiplying the cost estimations, the total cost is O(N<sup>5</sup>).

Comment: Just wanted to understand, the inner most loop is dependent on middle loop. The innermost loop will be running N times instead of N^2 as the condition says "k<j"?

Comment: @krishna_tandon Since `k` varies up to `j`, and `j` varies up to N², `k` will vary up to N² too.